# Open JQuery Datepicker by clicking on an image w/ no input field

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I want to have the JQuery Datepicker open when the user clicks on an image. There is no input field where the selected date appears afterwards; I'm just going to save the entered date to the server via Ajax.

Currently I have this code:

```
<img src='someimage.gif' id="datepicker" />

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
        }).click(function() { $(this).datepicker('show'); });
 });
```

But nothing happens when I click on the image. I have also tried saving the result of the datepicker() call to a global var and then calling datepicker('show') from the onclick() event of the image, but same result.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Turns out that a simple hidden input field does the job:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />
```

And then use the buttonImage attribute for your image, like normal:

```
    $("#dp").datepicker({
        buttonImage: '../images/icon_star.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',
     });
```

Initially I tried a text input field and then set a `display:none` style on it, but that caused the calendar to emerge from the top of the browser, rather than from where the user clicked. But the hidden field works as desired.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwcv8L9t/)

Comment: How can we set the `alignment` property when `input` is `hidden` type?

Comment: here's a jsfiddle if some one need it :-) 
-------->>>>>>
http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/M9Hj6/

Comment: I want to use it with date time picker but doesn't seem there is any option for it in extended date time pickers. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 24):

The jQuery documentation says that the datePicker needs to be attached to a SPAN or a DIV when it is not associated with an input box. You could do something like this:

```
<img src='someimage.gif' id="datepickerImage" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
    })
    .hide()
    .click(function() {
      $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#datepickerImage").click(function() {
       $("#datepicker").show(); 
    });
 });
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ubgj0hz4/3/)

Comment: This works, but strangely I lose some functionality with this monthly. For example, I don't get the scroll open animation effect. More importantly, the calendar doesn't go away when I click outside it.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of adding that click() method to #datepicker?

And by the way, I meant "method", not "monthly". Got calendars on the brain!

Comment: The reason for adding the click() method to the #datepicker is to make it hide, otherwise it will remain visible. Keep in mind that the standard behavior only works when the calendar is associated with a textbox. 

You could probably add an .blur() handler to make it hide when you move your mouse away from the calendar.

Comment: I want to use it with date time picker but doesn't seem there is any option for it in extended date time pickers. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 23):

If you are using an input field and an icon (like this example):

```
<input name="hasta" id="Hasta"  type="text" readonly  />
<a href="#" id="Hasta_icono" ></a>
```

You can attach the datepicker to your icon (in my case inside the A tag via CSS) like this:

```
$("#Hasta").datepicker();
  $("#Hasta_icono").click(function() { 
   $("#Hasta").datepicker( "show" );
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

To change the "..." when the mouse hovers over the calendar icon, You need to add the following in the datepicker options:

```
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: 'Click to show the calendar',
    buttonImageOnly: true, 
    buttonImage: 'images/cal2.png',
```

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="CalendarBlock">
    <input type="hidden">
</div>
```

CODE:

```
$CalendarBlock=$('.CalendarBlock');
$CalendarBlock.click(function(){
    var $datepicker=$(this).find('input');
    datepicker.datepicker({dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'});
    $datepicker.focus(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

Having a hidden input field leads to problems with datepicker dialog positioning (dialog is horizontally centered). You could alter the dialog's margin, but there's a better way.

Just create an input field and "hide" it by setting it's opacity to 0 and making it 1px wide. Also position it near (or under) the button, or where ever you want the datepicker to appear.

Then attach the datepicker to the "hidden" input field and show it when user presses the button.

HTML:

```
<button id="date-button">Show Calendar</button>
<input type="text" name="date-field" id="date-field" value="">
```

CSS:

```
#date-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    height 30px;
}

#date-field {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1px;
    height: 32px; // height of the button + a little margin
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
   $('#date-field').datepicker();

   $('#date-button').on('click', function() {
      $('#date-field').datepicker('show');
   });
});
```

Note: not tested with all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
   $("#datepicker").datepicker({
       //showOn: both - datepicker will come clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
       //showOn: button - datepicker will come only clicking the calendar icon
       showOn: 'button',
      //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
      buttonImage: 'http://theonlytutorials.com/demo/x_office_calendar.png',
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true,
      showAnim: 'slideDown',
      duration: 'fast',
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
```

The above code belongs to [this link](http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/jquery-date-picker-click-calendar-icon-image/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='someimage.gif' id="datepicker" />
<input type="hidden" id="dp" />

 $(document).on("click", "#datepicker", function () {
   $("#dp").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 'today'}).datepicker( "show" ); 
  });
```

you just add this code for image clicking or any other html tag clicking event. This is done by initiate the datepicker function when we click the trigger.