# MVC: How do you remove focus from a datepicker?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this Editor Template so that I have a datepicker set for date input.
See

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.DateTime?>" %>
<%:Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToLongDateString() : string.Empty), 
    new { @class = "datePicker" })%>
```

When I load a page with a date input field I automatically get the datepicker invoked. I would rather wait until the user clicks on the field or button.

I am thinking that I want to use a JQuery Blur command associated with this Editor Template to stop this happening. But is that the right way, can it be done like that, or is there a better way?

Comment: How are you attaching the date picker to the text field? By default jQuery shouldn't be showing the calendar on page load.

Comment: this `SO` question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1112035/413670

Comment: I am associating the Editor Template in the standard way with an HTML.EditorFor command.

Comment: @arame3333: But what does your JavaScript look like? We'd like to see more code.

Comment: @3nigma - I tried <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function() { $('.datepicker').blur(); }); </script> but it did not work.

Comment: Try using $('.datepicker').hide();

Comment: @arame3333 `blur` will fire when youe datepicker loses `focus` try `.hide()` and on `focus` or button `click` show it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the calendar to appear until something is clicked, then you can try the [showOn](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOn) option, possibly like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Calendar'
    });
})
```