# Calender Control in C# asp.net MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Hi people I having a slight problem I looking for the simplest way of using a calendar control in MVC3 asp.net C#. I have played around with MVC3 C# could not get the calender control to work I tried to hand write the code but i failed. I tried to find for some ASP.net examples did not succeed. The way i want to use the calendar is, when a user clicks on a date he or she is able to input information and it gets stored within a database. Is this possible to do? if so are there any examples out there that i may have missed or code that you could start me off to create a fresh one. I have been at this for nearly 2 months and deleted many tries since they did not work.

Thank You

Comment: I have tried the following: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc/using-the-html5-and-jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar-with-aspnet-mvc-part-4


http://www.antiyes.com/aspnet-mvc-calendar-helper

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/02/03/using-fullcalendar-jquery-component-with-asp-net-mvc.aspx

But i know you just going to ask so you know am just not asking for free code and then not reply it happened to me before

http://mvc.daypilot.org/mvc-3-razor-calendar-and-sql-server-tutorial-c-and-vb-net/

Comment: I knew you were going to do that ask me a question and when you got the answer and just vanish. If you were not going to help why ask a question?

Comment: If you were going to ask a question, why not add all relevant details? An accurate description of what you really want wouldn't hurt either. See the confusion below. Appointment texts are not really part of calendar controls, and neither is updating any database.

Comment: Yes they are, if you would have read the question properly maybe you would understand. "The way i want to use the calendar is, when a user clicks on a date he or she is able to input information and it gets stored within a database. Is this possible to do?"

Comment: Appointment was a example of what i have written: "when a user clicks on a date he or she is able to input information and it gets stored within a database. Is this possible to do?" "information" can be anything. An example of Appointments was there to show what "information" could stand for?

Comment: There is no point of asking a question if you have no answer. It is pointless, maybe next time read the question before just reading the first 2 or 3 sentences and then maybe you will understand what I am saying. Take care

Comment: Alright you want a control to operate over all 3 layers at once. Helpful answer: switch to WebForms.

Comment: Will try, but i am using MVC3 C# dont know if web form will be useful. The reason I cant find any answers is MVC3 is new. But thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

You could use a client side calendar. [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) is a good choice. It supports lots of functions including [inline display](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline).

Comment: Just visualize a calendar on a cshtml page and when you run the application, you click on a date from the calendar and then a input box appears and you insert some text such as a appointment for example. Just say you click on the 2nd of march and a input box appears and you write I have an appointment to see a doctor.

Comment: @user1137472, great, seems very easy. The jQuery UI datepicker could be perfect for this scenario. You could subscribe to the [`onSelect`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect) event which will be trigerred when the user selects a date so that you could toggle the visibility of some text input or whatever action you want to perform.

Comment: But that is the other-way around to what i wanted the input box picks the date and puts it inside the input box not the date showing the input box. Thanks for your help It seems there is not a way to do this as the example you gave me no where does it show a calender where i can select a date and input box appears it is the input box showing the date. Thanks anyways

Comment: @user1137472, you could associate the jQuery UI datepicker to a hidden input field if you don't want an input field to be visible but only a button. Here's an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127215/29407

Comment: To complex for me just want to select a date and input some information but thanks anyways

Comment: @user1137472, I wouldn't expect to find any easier solution. If that's too complex for you maybe you could start reading the documentation and playing with the examples in the jQuery UI site.

Comment: Thanks will play around with the site i appreciate the help, could you not write a example if you know what you are doing if that is a little too much i am asking it is ok will play around with the examples thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you mind to use a jQuery plugin?

Give [**FullCalendar**](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) a try.

Then you can easily create an action to fill up the appointments as well to grab the new ones created by the user, every thing works with ajax calls, so in MVC is really easy to accomplish this.

Let me know if you have trouble using this.

Comment: I have seen this but it will let you click on the date and input what information this is a control for moving tags around on date nothing is stored within a database a date can not be selected

Comment: You are wrong, you can click on a day and show an input form, just use the [`dayClick`](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/dayClick/) event

Comment: [here is an example](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/selectable.html) on how to create events, you have total control on what you can do, it's all up to you. You can simply show a modal dialog with a form

Comment: Where do i download the one you have total control on

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Telerik ASP.NET MVC controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx) (they have a calendar of course)?

They are dual licensed (commercial license and GPL). They usually have pretty good controls and build it upon jQuery, so it's easy to understand and extend if you need to.

Comment: They are not free you have to pay

Comment: Only if you can't live with the GPLv2 licensed version (http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/getting-started/licensing.aspx). And where did you say that it need to be free? If you are not coding for a living I'm pretty sure that GPLv2 is okay for you. If you are coding for a living it shouldn't be a problem to invest some money in your tools.