# How to fire jQuery UI DatePicker onclick?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

The standard code for DatePicker is:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

How to launch datepicker onclick event from inline HTML, I mean:

```
<input ... onclick="" >
```

and with no separate JS code?

I tried:

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onclick="$(function() {$('#datepicker').datepicker();});"></p>
```

But it's working only on second click.

How to make it work on first click?

Comment: Here's an answer of how to do that http://stackoverflow.com/a/1127215/1078487

Comment: thanks. I have just updated my q: How to launch datepicker onclick event from inline html <input ... onclick="" , and with no separate JS code?

Comment: not a good idea in the first place and there can't possibly be any reason it has to be an inline onclick with no other datepicker code in page

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="dp" onclick="$('#dp').datepicker();$('#dp').datepicker('show');"></p>​
```

That work by any chance?

I'm no expert, but I believe you were having to click it twice because the first click merely initialised it as a datepicker. After this initialising, it's behaving as a normal datepicker, regardless of the onclick.

Comment: thanks! that worked! from docs: datepicker( "show" ) - Call up a previously attached date picker.
So "$('#dp').datepicker()" - initialization;

Comment: thanks! that worked! from docs: datepicker( "show" ) - Call up a previously attached date picker.
1. So "$('#dp').datepicker()" - initialization; 2. $('#dp').datepicker('show'); - force showing datepicker. Is that right?

Comment: Yep, that's what it's doing. I think this not best practice though, and depending on how your program works, you may want to look at the .live function in jQuery? Anyway glad it helped.

Answer (score 6):

After you create datepicker, open it this way:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker('show')
```

Go to datepicker API docs look at methods tab, it's all there

Comment: as you can see in the q: I know how to use it with a separate js code. My aim is to use inline onlclick="" event execution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#datepic").datepicker({ showOn: 'button',buttonImage: 'image/calendar.gif'});

});
</script>

<input type="text" id="datepic" />
```

Answer (score 0):

like this one?

http://jsfiddle.net/tZXjR/

Comment: thanks. I have just updated my q: How to launch datepicker onclick event from inline html <input ... onclick="" , and with no separate JS code?