# jquery date picker but day month and year in separate dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a jquery date picker.  I need to select a date but after date selection from the calendar I need the date to divide into three separate drop downs. One for day one for month and one for year. Here is my jquery script.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

   $(function() {
    $( "#fullDate" ).datepicker({
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
       $('#day').val( dateText.split('/')[2] );
       $('#month').val( dateText.split('/')[1] );
   $('#year').val( dateText.split('/')[0] );
    }
 });
});
}); 
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input id="fullDate" type="text" style="display:block"></p>
day:<select name="day" id="day" style="width:100px">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>

 month:<select name="month" id="month" style="width:100px">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select>

year:<select name="year" id="year" style="width:100px">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
<option>4</option>
<option>5</option>
</select>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```

Comment: So what error you are getting?

Comment: the error is that after selecting the date from calender it do not display in day month and year in its related dropdowns.

Comment: Is split is working with IE .?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Working demo please click here** : ] http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/13/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/8/

In demo click on the text box and select dates and bingo you will get the drop downs auto populated.

Point to note `dateText.split('/')[2]` is year not day :) if you will switch over the place your code will work.

i.e. `dateText.split('/')[2]` : year ; `dateText.split('/')[0]` : month ; `dateText.split('/')[0]` : day rest demo will help you to make it clear.

The demo has extra bits but it will help you!

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $("#fullDate").datepicker({
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
        }
    });
});
```

**ANother Demo for image click:** http://jsfiddle.net/zwwY7/

**code**

```
$(function() {
    $("#fullDate").datepicker({
         buttonImage: 'icon_star.jpg',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $('#year').val(dateText.split('/')[2]);
            $('#month').val(dateText.split('/')[0]);
            $('#day').val(dateText.split('/')[1]);
        }
    });
});

​
```

**Images**
[image]

[image]

Comment: its working fine but what changes should i made if i want to click a calender image and get the whole functionality you mention me.??

Comment: Hi @KashifWaheed hmmm, will it be possible if you use my jsfiddle and create your issue - I will help you out. I am finding it hard to understand as in demo you can click on the calendar image that pops in http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/13/ I will put an image for you as well, let me know, happy to help you out :)

Comment: thank you very much sir Tats_innit. infact i am working locally yet there is noting live with me so that i could sent u the link i m really sorry for that. but for your convince i sent you this demo link http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/8/ in this demo there is a text box when click on it a calender appears and blah blah. i need the same but the difference is that i want to replace text box with an image and want to get the same functionality. hope u understand and sorry if u feeling trouble.

Comment: Hiya @KashifWaheed okies gotchya B-) - instead of input you want image here you go; read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112035/open-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-an-image-w-no-input-field ; Note: date picker can be used with `div` and `span` hope the link will give you enough code to chug on :) cheers!

Comment: @KashifWaheed here you go made a demo for you see the code inside for image: http://jsfiddle.net/zwwY7/ (NOw when you click on small question mark you will get the calendar) time for me to sleep soon :P but this will help you including the previous stack overflow link, cheers! (Oh and +1 to your question)

Comment: its superb thanx alot Mr.Tats_innit and every one else that post their solution for my questoin...

Comment: The problem with this though is that is assumes every  month has 31 days.  Feb for instance should show a number of days based on the year.

Answer (score 1):

Use the datepicker **onselect** method to get the date values you need :: [onselect info](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect)

Like:

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {            
        var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
        var month = datePieces[0];
        var day = datePieces[1];
        var year = datePieces[2];
        //define select option values for
        //corresponding element
        $('select#month').val(month);
        $('select#day').val(day);
        $('select#year').val(year);

}
```

Did you mean something like that

Comment: yes of course. Mr Tats_innit send me some demo links it solved my problem but now my question is that if i want to add an image instead of text box, mean there is a calendar image at the end of three drop downs and when i click the image a calender pop out and i select any date and it splits into day month and year as i mentioned before.i am new to jquery.thanks for help