# jQuery datepicker, separating date / month / year while selecting

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I wanted to separate date, month and year while submitting the form, and I thought using multiple altfield could be a solution, however, this is not working. Any light anyone please ? Thanks a lot.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      altField: "#y, #m, #d",
      altFormat: "yyyy, mm, dd"
    });
});


<form action="#">   
<input type="text" id="datepicker"><br />
<input type="text" name="y" />
<input type="text" name="m" />
<input type="text" name="d" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: Solved using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876696/jquery-date-picker-but-day-month-and-year-in-separate-dropdowns

Thanks

Comment: I wonder what takes you longer: posting a question or figure out the answer yourself. Hope that you know what I means :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gvAbv/258/)

```
$(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            alert("Year = "+dateText.split('/')[2] + " Month = "+ dateText.split('/')[0] + " Day =" + dateText.split('/')[1]);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The answer has been edited to provide "essential parts".