# jQuery UI datepicker without a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to use the jQuery UI datepicker without a text box? I just want to have the calendar icon that when clicked shows the calendar control. Then when a date is selected the control should disappear. Then I just want to capture the date selected and pass it to my own javascript function.

I've tried using it with spans and divs but the behavior is all wrong. It doesn't hide when a user selects a date. If I attach it to a hidden field as some have suggested, the datepicker can't be launched.

Comment: This might help: [Open JQuery Datepicker by clicking on an image w/ no input field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112035/open-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-an-image-w-no-input-field/)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that's where I started and tried all the strategies listed there to no avail.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a solution I have.

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qphza/1/

```
// Set up datepicker toggle functionality

$("#datepicker").hide();

$("#buttonHere").click(function(){

    $("#datepicker").toggle();
}); 

$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
      onSelect: function(value, date) { 
         alert('The chosen date is ' + value); 

         // Hide the datepicker div when something is selected

         $("#datepicker").hide(); 
      } 
});
```

Here's the HTML

```
<button id = "buttonHere">Click to show datepicker</button>

<div id = "datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: What's the associated HTML?

Comment: @Barmar Its in the JsFiddle link

Comment: You should include it in the answer, the fiddle is just for demonstration purposes.

Comment: For those interested, use `defaultDate` datepicker option to specify the date.

Answer (score 1):

Had to use a kludge but I got it to work. Here's the jQuery.

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "btn_calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect:function(selectedDate){
                alert(selectedDate);
       }
    });
  });
```

Here's the HTML.

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker" size="1" readonly style="outline: none; color: #FFFFFF; border: 0px solid #000000;"/>
```

Basically I made the textbox invisible and readonly without actually "hiding" it. But the behavior works. Seems to be the only way to get a datepicker without a visible textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "ShowOn" option to use datepicker with an icon.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      onSelect:function(selectedDate){
                your_function(selectedDate);
       }

    });
  });
```

also you can use the "onSelect" option to pass the selected date to your javascript function.

Comment: Unfortunately, unless datepicker is a textbox (which I don't want), the behavior is wrong. If I make datepicker a div/span then the calendar doesn't disappear after selecting a date.

Comment: you can hide the input field.

Comment: Adding onSelect breaks it. No datepicker is visible as soon as I add onSelect. Are you sure it's not deprecated?

Comment: Ignore that last comment. onSelect works.

Comment: @Legion look at my answer it's exactly what you need.

Comment: I've tried it. It doesn't work properly unless attached to a textbox field. Hiding the textbox field causes the datepicker to hide and not respond to clicks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pxeFM/8/ this does not show the behavior you stated.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the datepicker to a hidden input and then just assign the selected date to whatever you need it to e.g. a label.

```
$('#hiddenInput').datepicker({
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        $('#calendarDay').text(selectedDate);
        $('#hiddenInput').datepicker('destroy');
    }
});
```

This is a jsFiddle showing that:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxeFM/8/