# Make input look like anchor link (AKA jQueryUI datepicker without input)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I wish to make an input element look just like an anchor link.  Furthermore, it should look like a link where the x-editable plugin is applied to it.  My attempt is displayed below.  My difficulty is the underline extends past the text, and the text width is not always the same.  Ideally, the input width would always be the width of the text (JavaScript solutions are okay).  I also have problems with the before/after clicked color, but suppose I could just eliminate this from the other links on the page.

```
.inputLink {
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    color:#0000ff;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #0088cc;
    text-decoration: none;
    /* width:75px; */
}
```

Why am I doing this?

I need jQuery datepicker (actually timepicker) to be initiated by clicking the current date.  I've seen several solutions, but believe my solution posted below (and also at http://jsbin.com/tadaqomure/1/) is cleaner provided I can figure out the input CSS.  If you feel I should be doing differently, please provide a comment.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  

        <style type="text/css">
            .inputLink {
                border: none;
                outline: none;
                background-color: transparent;
                font-family: inherit;
                font-size: inherit;
                cursor: pointer;
                color:#0000ff;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #0088cc;
                text-decoration: none;
                /* width:75px; */
            }
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon/1.4.5/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href= "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/jqueryui-editable/css/jqueryui-editable.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.1/jqueryui-editable/js/jqueryui-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function(){
                $('#text').editable();
                $("#datetime").datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <span>Normal Link:</span>
            <a href="#" id="text">test</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <span>Datetime Fake Link:</span>
            <input class="inputLink" id="datetime" type="text" readonly value="1/05/1984" />
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Why would it need to be an `<input>` at all? Is it supposed to be editable with javascript disabled?

Comment: @bergie.  I am not concerned about non-javascript users for this application.  I suppose I could apply it to a `span` or `div` (the only other two supported by datepicker), but then will need to manage hiding the dialog and showing it upon being clicked.  Thought it would just be easier to make the input look like a link.  Maybe not...

Comment: Why are `<a>`s not supported by the datepicker?

Comment: @Bergi  Don't know but they are not.  I've read several posts on this site about it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112035/open-jquery-datepicker-by-clicking-on-an-image-w-no-input-field/1112135#1112135, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198741/jquery-ui-datepicker-making-a-link-trigger-datepicker, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491535/jquery-ui-datepicker-without-a-textbox